# Remover da tabela várias linhas ao mudar de estado

Tags: javascript

Ao alterar o estado das linhas da tabela, pretendo que o usuários não as veja. Neste caso mudo o estado em várias linhas ao mesmo tempo. Então ao alterar o estado das linhas, quero removê-las da tabela.

Estou a fazer desta forma:

```
function inserir_registo()
{    
var Ids = [];
$("input[name^='teste1']").each(function() {Ids.push(this.value)});

var EstadoFinals = [];
$("select[name^='EstadoFinal1']").each(function() {EstadoFinals.push($(this).val())});

var dadosajax = {
 'Id[]' : Ids,
 'EstadoFinal[]' : EstadoFinals
};
$.ajax({
    url: './encomendaaprovada',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: dadosajax,
    error: function(){
      $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
    },
    success: function(result)
    { 
    for( var i = 0; i < Ids.length; i++){ 
      if(dadosajax.EstadoFinal != '2'){
      Ids.remove();
    } 
   }
  }
});
}
```

O código que estou a usar para remover da função acima:

```
var Ids = [];
$("input[name^='teste1']").each(function() {Ids.push(this.value)});

success: function(result)
{
  for( var i = 0; i < Ids.length; i++){ 
  if(dadosajax.EstadoFinal != '2'){
  Ids.remove();
  } 
}
```

Retorne este erro e não remove as linhas:

> ?preview_id=2501&preview_nonce=dd04e65715&preview=true:784 Uncaught
>   TypeError: Ids.remove is not a function at Object.success
>   (?preview_id=2501&preview_nonce=dd04e65715&preview=true:784) at i
>   (jquery.min.js:2) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith]
>   (jquery.min.js:2) at A (jquery.min.js:4) at XMLHttpRequest.

Tabela:

```
<table class="table table-responsive" id="employee_ta">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="display:none">Id</th>
<th>Data Encomenda</th>
<th>Tipo de Produto</th>
<th>Produto</th>
<th>Quantidade</th>
<th>Requerente</th>
<th>Destino</th>
<th>Observacoes</th>
<th>Última Aprovação</th>
<th>Último Preço</th>
<th>Estado</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="<?php echo $produto["Id"]; ?>">
<td style="display:none"><input type="text" rows="4" name="teste1[]" id="teste1" value="<?php echo $produto["Id"]; ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $produto["Data"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $produto["Identificacao"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $produto["Produto"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $produto["Quantidade"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $produto["Requerente"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $produto["Destino"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $produto["Observacoes"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ln1['DataAprovacao']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ln2['Preco']; ?> €</td>
<td><?php echo $produto["Estado"]; ?></td>          
</tr> 
</tbody>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça dessa maneira pra remover um item específico de um `array`:

```js
  for( var i = 0; i < Ids.length; i++){ 
  if(dadosajax.EstadoFinal != '2'){
   Ids.splice($.inArray(Ids[i], Ids), 1);
   $('tr[id="'+ Ids[i] +'"]').remove();
  }
}
```

Mais informações: 
[`.splice()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)
[`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: não retorna nenhuma erro, mas também não remove as linhas da tabela.

Comment: Ai ele vai remover os items do seu array, se quer que remova os items da tabela tem que postar seu codigo HTML da tabela para montar um seletor

Comment: Adicionei html da minha tabela

Comment: Resposta modificada @Bruno

Comment: é mesmo isso que pretendo. Só existe um problema, por exemplo na tabela existem 4 linhas, altero o estado às 4 linhas mas só remove duas.

Comment: Você pode debugar o código e ir printando no console para adaptar o código a sua necessidade.